# JQuery causing a flicker when setting a div's display to none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'll start by saying that this issue isn't related to a page load.  I know that fixing the page load flickering is a common question asked here.

I have a  tag that contains a form used to insert data into a MySQL database.  This tag is placed at the end of my index.php document.  I then set the CSS to be

```
   display: none; position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px;
```

When the appropriate button is clicked on the page, I have an onclick listener set up that changes the CSS to block:

```
    $("#insertForm").css("display", "block");
```

Everything is fine at this point, but when the user clicks a link (with an `onclick` listener associated with it) to hide the form, it causes a nasty screen flicker while hiding the div tag.  I'm using the

```
    $("#insertForm").css("display", "none");
```

command to hide the  tag.

Any ideas how to fix this flicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Try to prevent the browser default behavior:

```
$('#clicker').on('click', function( e ){

    e.preventDefault();
  
    // do wat you do

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Anyway try to set the **initial** `display:none;` inside the CSS, that way you'll secure any filckerings caused by the DOM being loaded and just after - your element being hided by JS (jQuery)

#### 2.Reading again your question

I can assume that your element, being at the end of the page, looses it's **HEIGHT** by being set to `display:none;` 
causing the `document` to loose `scrollHeight` - there the *jump/flick* of your page.

Try to go with `visibility` instead of `display`.

Comment: You are exactly right.  I realized this a little bit after posting this question.  I had forgotten to return false; at the end of my click event.  Thanks for the quick reply.  :)